# Logs for Visual Studio Shutdown error?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, logging

Every time I close visual studio it tells me that there has been an error.

Eventually it tries to restart visual studio.  This only happens when I close Visual Studio.  To have it reopen visual studio after I just closed it is a bit frustrating.

Is there a log I can go look at to see what is causing the failure?  (I have a few addins installed.  And I am hoping that I don't have to uninstall them one by one to see which is causing this issue.)

Comment: I have the same problem. Had it on my old win7 32 bit and now on my new win7 64 bit. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If it's trying to restart itself, something should show up in the Windows/Applications event log in the Administrative Tools list.